# Delete on many to one relation is not persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete an entity from a Many to One relationship. It doesn`t throw any error, but it seems that the item is not deleted and I do not know why. These are my classes:

Client Entity:

```
public class Client extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private LocalDate dateOfRegister;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =
            FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Rental> rentals = new HashSet<>();

    ..............
    }
```

Movie Entity:

```
public class Movie extends BaseEntity<Long>{

    private String title;
    private int year;
    private int duration;
    private String genre;
    private double imdbRating;
    private String trailerLink;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =
            FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Rental> rentals = new HashSet<>();

    ..................
}
```

Rental (link) entity:

```
public class Rental implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @Column(name = "dateRented")
    private LocalDate dateRented;

    @Column(name = "dateDue")
    private LocalDate dateDue;

     .............
}
```

PrimaryKey class:

```
public class RentalPK implements Serializable {
    private Movie movie;
    private Client client;
}
```

In the controller, I do the following:

```
@Override
    public void deleteRental(RentalPK rentalPK) {
        try {
            rentalRepository.deleteById(rentalPK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Could someone please explain why it is not deleting?

Comment: Your RentalPK class most probably doesn't override equals() and hashCode() correctly. Do not use composite, functional IDs. Use a purely technical, auto-generated, single-column ID, and everything will be easier and more efficient.

Comment: @JBNizet I know it would be easier, but my app requires me to use a composite primary key. I have also tried that instead of using the objects Movie and Client in the RentalPK class, to use only the id's of these 2 ( private Long movieID, private Long clientID), but it still didn't work. ( I thought that maybe in this I won`t have problems with equals and hashcode). Any suggestion on how to figure out what is actually wrong? Thank you! :D

Comment: Why would the app require that? Anyway, I already said what I think is incorrect: equals() and hashCode(). That's what I think is actually wrong. But I can only guess, since you didn't post these methods. I don't even know if they exist.

Comment: They exist, i use the spring annotation to generate them @EqualsAndHashCode. But I think they work fine because the findById() method works fine

Comment: Let me guess (again): you're also using `@EqualsAndHashCode` on your entities (those annotations are not Spring annotations, BTW, they're Lombok annotations). If so, don't. But once again, unless you have an existing database schema already used by other applications and that you can't change, don't use composite PKs.

Comment: No, on those 2 entities I am not using @EqualsAndHashCode, I have written them myself. And I am not the only one working with this database, that`s why I cannot change the structure and make a simple PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! It seems it was because of the CascadeType.ALL in the Movie and Client entities. It seems that the CascadeType.ALL contains also CascadeType.PERSIST which says that the link entity(rental in my case) can be removed only from the parents. So I have fixed the problem by replacing `CascadeType.ALL` with `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

EDIT: I do not know if this is the exact explanation but it worked.